# Paste a screen shot in a richtext box

Tags: web-part

I am creating a custom webpart by using SharePoint object model (using visual studio), which has a rich text box control on it and I'm trying to paste a screen shot of the screen.  It seems that the richtext box does not support this functionaliy.  Is there any way we can achieve this?

```
</asp:Label><SharePoint:InputFormTextBox
runat="server" ID="respRichTextBox" ValidationGroup="CreateCase" Rows="10" RichText="true"
TextMode="MultiLine" RichTextMode="FullHtml" AllowHyperlink="true">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not add images copied from Clipboard. You may need to upload it to images library (or any location that html's href attribute can refer) and refer it from there.

Comment: if it is impossible with sharepoint richtextbox..can it be possible using asp.net's richtextbox?

Comment: I think both will behave same because the rich text box's underlying data is HTML and HTML needs src attribute for the img tag which displays the image.

Answer (score 1):

You would need an ActiveX control to grab the clipboard and handle the image. Check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ClipboardActiveX.aspx